# Saving .3ds or .obj files using Blender API

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, blender

I would like to create 3ds or .obj files with python. For example I want to create a cube with python programming and I want to save it in a file like "cube.obj"; how can I do that?

Solutions that I have tried:

1) Blender API for python

- I can create 3d models but I cannnot export them as a file. Or if I want to export them then I need to open blender and paste my code in text editor.

2) OpenGl for python
- I can create models but I cannot save the model as a file.

Comment: After a quick Google search, using Blender API: https://blenderartists.org/t/saving-via-the-api/557973/2

Comment: I will try your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to export as OBJ.

```
import bpy    
bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath="", use_selection=True)
```

`filepath` is where you want to export the model

`use_selection` is if you want to export the whole scene or just the selected part

There are a lot more you can do with this function via arguments you can read about it [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_scene.html#bpy.ops.export_scene.obj)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Blender API for python as [discussed here](https://blenderartists.org/t/saving-via-the-api/557973/2), you can save a model using the [`save_as_mainfile`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile) function:

```
import bpy
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="C:\example\file\path")
```

`filepath` is the path to which the model should be written.

Answer (score 0):

As of Blender 4.0 (Feb 2024):

`bpy.ops.wm.obj_export(filepath=filepath, export_selected_objects=True, export_materials=False)`